# select on-change to populate specific options in another select not work on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, hide, show

this example is working fine on chrome, firefox ... but not on Safari

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
    var id  = $(this).val();
  $("#select2 option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == id) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
     var arrVal = $(this).val().split(',');
     if(arrVal.indexOf(id)>-1)
        $(this).show();
     else
        $(this).hide();
    }
    });
});
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/s41rjkhL/5/[1](https://jsfiddle.net/s41rjkhL/5/)

Any Idea how to solve that? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `<option>` element cannot be hidden in some browsers. You can wrap it with `<span>` to hide it:

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    var id  = $(this).val();

    $('#select2 option').each(function() {
        var arrVal = $(this).val().split(',');

        if ($.inArray(id, arrVal) > -1) {
            if ($(this).parent('span').length)
                $(this).unwrap();
        } else {
            if ($(this).parent('select').length)
                $(this).wrap('<span>');
        }
    });
});
```

See this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/s41rjkhL/62/

Comment: any way to let the first option in select2 "<option value="0"> Select Item</option>" to be always displayed ? as in  https://jsfiddle.net/s41rjkhL/5/1 example